# RRAS VPN Set-Up -- Need Insight From Windows Server 2008 Admin

Tags: windows, vpn, pptp

I am hoping that I don't get too many thumbs down for this, I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction on a project that I am now regretting picking up.

I am a Linux Admin by trade, when I was informed that someone needed a Windows Server for QuickBooks and a VPN set-up I thought "Sure, how hard can this be?".  We ordered the Server and a Cisco RVS4400N Router for VPN.  I failed at reading the fine print that it doesn't actually do PPTP or L2TP over IPSEC and it isn't a real Cisco VPN router in the sense that I can use the cisco options on an iPad or iPhone so it won't work for my client's needs.

While scrambling to find an option I offered my client one of my spare Linksys routers that I told him I would flash for his needs.  The problem is my WRT54G's are Version 8 routers and they don't have enough flash memory to support the version of DD-WRT that can do PPTP VPN.

What I think would be a good idea would be to set up RRAS since we already have the Windows server and it should be simple enough and won't cost my client anything else as far as money.  The problem is I am not sure how to go about this.  I can find guides online but I have a few questions:

1) Will this even work, if the server has a static IP will the router set for PPTP pass through pass the VPN traffic correctly to the server or will the server need a static IP as well?

2) Is this free with Windows 2008 R2 or do I need to buy another license to make this work?

3) While I can find a guide online is there anyone who knows of a suggested guide?

The game plan is to go down and finish this project on Wednesday.  I have to get some sleep now before I go work my Graveyard shift.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) The server will need a static IP address, otherwise how will you configure the port forwarding for PPTP?

2) RRAS is free with Windows Server.

3) http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000103.htm

More importantly though - PPTP isn't secure AT ALL.  I get that you don't want the client to have to spend money, but seriously, you should look at investing in another solution.  An entry level Cisco ASA 5505 is pretty cheap and has IPSEC clients for all major operating systems.